# Error with overloaded relational operators

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading

The problem seems to exist for all the overloaded relational to operators. So I will use the overloaded >= as an example.

My error is:

```
P1TestV02.cpp:(.text+0x223b): undefined reference to Date::operator>=(Date const&) const'
```

in my DateTime.h file the overloaded operator is listed as:

```
bool const operator >=(const Date& rhsObj);
```

it is public and under the class Date.

in the DateTime.cpp file it is written as:

```
bool const Date::operator>=(const Date& rhsObj)
 {
if(*this >= rhsObj)
    return true;
else
    return false;
 }
```

The P1TestV02.cpp is hidden (P1Test.o)and it is simply a driver program. I don't get this error with my own main.

Comment: So in order to perform `>=`, you.. perform `>=`? Interesting...

Comment: Looks like you've declared both `const` and non-`const` overloads, but only implemented the latter. You only want a `const` version, unless it does something very unlike a comparison.